# How to stream my laptop screen to the TV?

Tags: streaming, sharing, tv

Recently I bought a Samsung Smart TV and with my Android mobile phone (using an app called Wifi Display) I can stream what I see on the mobile to the TV.

Is this feature available on Ubuntu? I would like to share my screen to the TV without wires, like I do with the Android.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this tutorials will help you for stream you screen. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv95HPXbwHU

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abdul, but I'm looking for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQo6fgJ6eqU but using Ubuntu (or GNU/Linux in general)

Comment: You can get some help from this links for stream your ubuntu screen on TV. http://danielj.se/2012/09/09/how-to-live-stream-your-ubuntu-desktop/